# How can i write a query by using Nest Elasticsearch by C# ?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

My question is simple. I can write a very awesome queries in postman ;

POST :  localhost:9200/logstash-2017.08.28/_search?pretty=true

```html
{
 "query":{
  "match":{
   
   "level":"Error"
  }
 }
 
}
```

But I have to this thing inside of C# code by using nest framework.But i can not do that can you help me?

```js
   var response = EsClient().Search<DocumentAttributes>(s => s
                .Index("logstash-2017.09.18")
                .Type("json")
                .Query(q => q
                .Term(p => p.level, "Error")));

             //.Query(q => q.Raw(@"level:Error")));
             //      .Type("type").Query(q => q.Raw(@"{""match_all"":{}}")));
```

How can i write down by writing query or by using fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are not the same. For `json` query you specified the following path `localhost:9200/logstash-2017.08.28/_search?pretty=true`, which means you are going to search for all documents in index `logstash-2017.08.28`.

Lets see what you have in query written using NEST.

1. `Index` method means that you are going to search for all documents in the given index
2. `Type` method means that you are going to query all documents in given index which has the given type. In your case type is `json`. So `Type` method is for defining on which type of documents are you going to search.

So, the difference between your queries is that in first case you are querying all the documents in the index, but in second case you are querying all the documents in the index with type `json`.

Comment: please don't focus on wrong part of question. you can use like that :  localhost:9200/logstash-2017.08.28/json/_search

Comment: So your document name is `json`?

Comment: You are using match query in first query and term query in second query